# Impossible to retrieve the attachment url

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have the piece article with a field for files

```
module.exports = {
extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
name: 'article',
label: 'Article',
pluralLabel: 'Articles',
orderings: true,
addFields: [
 Other fields...
 {
    name: 'files',
    label: 'Files',
    type: 'singleton',
    widgetType: 'apostrophe-files'
  },
 ]
};
```

And in the html I've use the apostrophe-files widget

```
  {{ apos.singleton(data.piece, 'files', 'apostrophe-files') }}
```

It works fine when I show them in the html, but when I click the links created to download the file, it gives me the error  in the console.

> Template warning: Impossible to retrieve the attachment url since it is missing, a default icon has been set. Please fix this ASAP!

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You haven't made a project-level `apostrophe-pieces/views/widget.html` ?. Any chance for a small sample project?

Comment: @StuartRomanek No I didn't make any widget.html, I thought that using the apostrope-files widget it should download the pdf that I added in the model to the article that I'm showing in the article show page. Should I create that piece for apostrophe-files? If you are asking about a widget for article, I didn't create a widget because all I want to show is in the template. About the other question, do you mean to clarify better here an example of the project, or to share a repository of an example?

Comment: I just re created your setup and the files widget is working as expected. Without a sample repo I'm not sure how to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't now exactly why, but it seems that it didn't work because I've uploaded the file a few days ago, and the url of the attachment changed for some reason. I put in the trash the files, and added new ones and it worked fine.